# Multiplying a Column by -1 Based on Another Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I'm writing an SSRS report that will change the value of one of the fields based on the value of another field in the same row. Would the best way to do it via SQL?

i.e.-Multiply `FieldX` (float) by `-1` if the value of `FieldY` ends with `D`,`DA`, or 'DB', etc.

I was initially looking at using a case statement, however I was getting a little stuck at work today. Any ideas? The SQL already uses a union, sums and grouping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to do it in SQL with a `case` statement. You can always break up the `or`s into their own `when...then` block, but it works just as well this way. Enjoy!

```
select
    case
        when right(FieldY, 1) = 'D'
             or right(FieldY, 2) = 'DA'
             or right(FieldY, 2) = 'DB'
        then FieldX * (-1)
        else FieldX
    end as FieldX
from
    table
```

Now, if you want to know if it ends with 'D' or 'D?' where '?' is any letter, then:

```
select
    case
        when right(FieldY, 1) = 'D' then FieldX * (-1)
        when left(right(FieldY, 2), 1) = 'D' then FieldX * (-1)
        else FieldX
    end as FieldX
from
    table
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the second example. Simple when you know how!